# Buscar Registro Anterior (Kilometragem)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando montar um relatório para gestão de dos abastecimentos. Tenho Uma Tabela de Abastecimentos com os seguintes campos:

```
DataAbastecimento,
CódigoVeiculo,
KmAbastecimento,
Quantidade,
Valor
```

No Relatório que estou fazendo, preciso saber o KM Percorrido...então segue exemplo:

```
Veiculo Data Abastecimento  KM     KM Anterior
999     02/06/2016          10.000 Buscar o Último KM de Abastecimento de Maio
999     08/06/2016          10.800 10.000
999     11/06/2016          11.300 10.800
999     19/06/2016          13.200 11.300
```

Até a coluna KM, é uma busca simples...porém esse KM Anterior estou me batendo algum tempo.

Alguém já se deparou com isso?

Comment: Coloca um exemplo de sql para pegar os dados que você quer. Assim fica mais fácil montar um que lhe atenda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi criando uma [FUNCTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186755(v=sql.120).aspx) para o cálculo da KM anterior. A solução fica mais bonita.

```
create function dbo.fn_km_abastecimento_anterior
(
  @codigoVeiculo as int,
  @dataAbastecimento as date
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @KM int
    SELECT @KM=MAX(a.kmAbastecido)
  FROM abastecimentos a (nolock)
  WHERE a.codigoVeiculo = @codigoVeiculo
    AND a.dataAbastecimento < @dataAbastecimento
  RETURN ISNULL(@KM,0)
END
GO
```

Na sua consulta final, você chama a sua função como coluna.

```
select 
  a.dataAbastecimento,
  a.codigoVeiculo,
  a.kmAbastecido,
  dbo.fn_km_abastecimento_anterior(a.codigoVeiculo, a.dataAbastecimento) as kmAnterior,
  a.qtde,
  a.valor
from abastecimentos a (nolock)
```

Comment: Com esse código ficou bem mais fácil...resolvido

Comment: Se serviu, não esquece de marcar a resposta como solução para a questão. Abs.